# Problem in finding the diameter of a tree using depth-first search

Tags: c++, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am writing the code for finding the maximum cost diameter of a tree. I am using depth first technique in which I find out the farthest node from the node(which can be the root node) and then find the farthest node from that node.

For example if the input looks like this:

```
8
7
1 2 5
2 7 6
2 4 2
4 5 1
4 3 9
1 8 3
8 6  4
```

Where 1st line contains the no of nodes, 2nd line mentions no of updations in the tree.The next n lines contains the two nodes and the weight of the path joining them.

The corresponding output should be:

```
6
23
```

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<limits.h>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

int x;
int weight=0;

void dfsutil(int node, int n, int count, int **adj, int &maxcount, bool visited[])
{
    visited[node]=true;
    count++;
    for( auto i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(!visited[i] && adj[node][i]!=0)
        {
            if(count>=maxcount)
            {
              maxcount=count;
              weight+=adj[node][i];
              x=i;
            }
            dfsutil(i,n, count, adj, maxcount, visited);
        }
    }
}

void dfs(int node, int n, int** adj, int &maxcount)
{
    bool visited[n+1];
    int count=0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       visited[i]=false;

    dfsutil(node, n, count+1, adj, maxcount, visited);
}

int diameter(int n, int **adj)
{
    int maxcount;
    maxcount=INT_MIN;
    dfs(1,n,adj,maxcount);
    dfs(x,n,adj,maxcount);
    return maxcount;
}

int main()
{
    int n,q,i,q1,q2,w;
    cout<<"Enter the number of nodes in the tree"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the number of queries"<<endl;
    cin>>q;
    int **adj=new int *[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        adj[i]=new int[n];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=q;i++)
    {
        cin>>q1>>q2>>w;
        adj[q1-1][q2-1]=w;
        adj[q2-1][q1-1]=w;
    }
    cout<<"The diameter is "<<diameter(n,adj)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is **two** problem that exist in this code:

i) The output should be 6 instead I get 4. What is the problem I can't find out.

ii) What if when two or more leaf nodes are at the same level but have different weights, the maximum cost diameter should take the path with maximum total weights. For example here, in case of `4->3` and `4->5` which have weights `9` and `1` and any one of the path can come into consideration while calculating diameter but while calculating the cost, the path with weight `9` i.e., `4->3` should be chosen. How to check for this condition?

Comment: I don't see anything C++14 specific in your question or the code you show, so I edited the tags to plain C++.

Comment: @Sorry for the wrong tag. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: For anyone in/will be in this feed, may I know somehow what is the reason for getting a downvote for a question. Just now, I got a downvote apparently for no reason. If the downvote is due to question is not as per the guidelines, one must mention it in the comments. This way it demotivates the questioner and it is possible to vote down a good question. Anyways this should be fixed by admin. Any idea where to lodge complaints regarding stackoverflow.

Comment: Re downvotes: Code questions require a minimal reproducible example but "minimal" means the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Finding such code anyway is a debugging fundamental.) Document the first point in execution where that extended code doesn't do what you expect. Since you say you don't even have a correct algorithm, you need to tell us what other result, which is not your overall goal, this code is supposed to return. And explain why/how it would. But--why write this code when you don't have an algorithm for your goal?

Comment: Hi. Today I have tried to give some of your posts some comments re improvement--before I found this comment. (Without downvotes, although they merit them.) Re "If the downvote is due to question is not as per the guidelines, one must mention it in the comments."--No, that is not how the site works. [help] (What is "fixed by admin"?) Re "lodge complaints regarding stackoverflow"--See help at [meta] & [meta.se]. (Hint: Don't presume to know what should be complained about when you are uninformed.) (Why didn't you just google 'where to lodge complaints regarding stackoverflow'?) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code, I've found several mistakes. For example, your `dfsUtil` implementation is not correct. As it is a weighted tree, you should be comparing based on the edge weights, not on counting the number of nodes. Your indexing is also a mess. Either use a `0` based indexing or `1` based indexing consistently. Mixing two of these makes debugging a lot harder. Lastly, you're passing a lot of information to the function. You should encapsulate this information inside a `class`. It makes your life a whole lot easier. Below is my take on what you're trying to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Edge{
    public:
        int node,weight;

        Edge() = default;
        Edge(int n, int w) : node(n), weight(w) {}
};

class TreeDiameterInfo{
    public:
        int endPointA, endPointB, diameter;

        TreeDiameterInfo() = default;
        TreeDiameterInfo(int eA, int eB, int d) : endPointA(eA), endPointB(eB), diameter(d){}
};

class Graph{
    static constexpr int MAX_NODE = 100;

    int nodes,edges;
    std::vector <Edge> adjList[MAX_NODE + 5];
    std::vector <int> visited;
    std::vector <int> distance;

    public:
        Graph() = default;

        void addEdge(int nodeA, int nodeB,int weight){
            adjList[nodeA].emplace_back(Edge(nodeB,weight));
            adjList[nodeB].emplace_back(Edge(nodeA,weight));
        }

        void takeInput(){
            std::cin >> nodes >> edges;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < edges ; ++i){
                int endA,endB,weight;
                std::cin >> endA >> endB >> weight;
                addEdge(endA,endB,weight);
            }
        }

        void printGraph(){
            std::cout << "===== Printing Graph =====\n";
            for(int i = 1 ; i <= nodes ; ++i){      
                std::cout << "Node " << i << ": ";
                for(int j = 0 ; j < adjList[i].size() ; j++){
                    std::cout << "(" << adjList[i][j].node << "," << adjList[i][j].weight << ")";
                    if(j != adjList[i].size() - 1) std::cout << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }
        }

        void dfs(int source, int &bestDistance, int &bestNode){
            visited[source] = 1;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < adjList[source].size() ; ++i){
                int adjacentNode = adjList[source][i].node;
                int costToNode = adjList[source][i].weight;
                if(!visited[adjacentNode]){
                    distance[adjacentNode] = distance[source] + costToNode;
                    if(bestDistance < distance[adjacentNode]){
                        bestDistance = distance[adjacentNode];
                        bestNode = adjacentNode; 
                    }
                    dfs(adjacentNode, bestDistance, bestNode);
                }
            }
        }

        void initialize(){
            visited = std::vector <int> (MAX_NODE + 5, 0) ;
            distance = std::vector <int> (MAX_NODE + 5, 0) ;
        }

        TreeDiameterInfo treeDiameter(){
            int farthestNodeFromRoot = -1, distanceFromRoot = -1;
            initialize();
            dfs(1, distanceFromRoot, farthestNodeFromRoot);
            int farthestNodeFromDiameterEndPoint = -1, farthestDistanceFromDiameterEndPoint = -1;
            initialize();
            dfs(farthestNodeFromRoot, farthestDistanceFromDiameterEndPoint, farthestNodeFromDiameterEndPoint);
            return TreeDiameterInfo(farthestNodeFromRoot, farthestNodeFromDiameterEndPoint, farthestDistanceFromDiameterEndPoint); 
        }
};

int main(){
    Graph g;
    g.takeInput();
    g.printGraph();
    TreeDiameterInfo treeDiameterInfo = g.treeDiameter();
    std::cout << "Tree Diameter: " << treeDiameterInfo.diameter << "\n";
    std::cout << "Two end points of tree diameter: " << treeDiameterInfo.endPointA << " " << treeDiameterInfo.endPointB << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
===== Printing Graph =====
Node 1: (2,5) (8,3)
Node 2: (1,5) (7,6) (4,2)
Node 3: (4,9)
Node 4: (2,2) (5,1) (3,9)
Node 5: (4,1)
Node 6: (8,4)
Node 7: (2,6)
Node 8: (1,3) (6,4)
Tree Diameter: 23
Two end points of tree diameter: 3 6
```